# Silex routes, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, routes, url-rewriting, silex

I am using htaccess like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /link/application/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

with simple index.php in /application/ folder like this

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../framework/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->get('/', function() {
    return 'Hello!';
});

$app->run();
```

and when i am trying to access localhost/link, Silex gives me an error

```
NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /link/"
```

so to fix it i need to change my $app->get to

```
$app->get('/link/', function() {
```

is there any methods to use RewriteEngine but not to rewrite Silex route (leave it as "/") ?
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If Silex is placed in a subdirectory the additional .htaccess RewriteCond for directories is needed, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /link/application
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

if your server is running Apache >= 2.2.16 you can use the FallbackResource:

```
FallbackResource /kit2/bootstrap.php
```

instead of the above code in your .htaccess.